# Meteor trying to get Facebook details

Tags: facebook, meteor

I am trying to get the user birthday and user location.

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
 facebook: ['user_birthday', 'user_location'],}});
```

When I sign in with facebook, it does ask me for the permissions for these.

```
var service = _.pairs(user.services)[0];
var serviceName = service[0];
var serviceData = service[1];
```

All my facebook details are retrieved from serviceData but birthday and location are not there. Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to fetch those information Facebook graph API.

The Facebook `accessToken` will available in `users` collections.
you will get it in users collection document as follows-

```
{

 ..........
services:
{
  facebook:{
   accessToken: <actual-fb-acesstoken>

  }
.....

}
```

With this access token you can get whatever information you want from facebook

One such reference is as follows -

https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-facebook-login/blob/master/server%2Faccounts.coffee#L1

Comment: do you think you can help me with doing the same thing but on google and twitter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872055/meteor-trying-to-get-user-twitter-google-details